# Writing to Text Files as a Struct vs.Cell Array

Tags: matlab

So I am trying to write data to a .txt file and I have encountered some difficulties. My understanding is that if I want to write struct data to a text file I need to first convert it to a table using `struct2table` and then use `writetable` to write it to the file. When I do this, however, the data is comma delimited in the text file. I really like the table format as it appears in MATLAB, but I can't find a way to make it appear that way in the text file (I assume that Excel reads in data that is comma delimited, which is why the data is formatted that way). Now, if I format the data as a cell array and then write that to the .txt file, then it looks great; however, the struct format is nice in that I can access data points easier and plot the data. So, I am a little lost on what route I should take to solve this problem. One idea I had was to format the data as a struct array and then when I want to write it to a .txt convert it to a cell array. The other idea I had was to somehow manipulate the data format when I use `writetable`. I can, for instance, change the delimiter to a tab and that looks great, except that the data does not line up (e.g. if I have `Frequency` and `Power` as column headers, the numbers below them in the table are not aligned with those headers). This, of course, is trivial if using `fprintf'; but I can't use that on a struct array (from what I understand).

I hope this is comprehensive enough, but if there is anything else I can provide please let me know and thank you in advance.

Comment: I would check the `Delimiter` option of the `writetable` function. You can use it to change the delimiter to space, tab, semi-colon, etc.

Comment: An example of what your data looks like in MATLAB and what you want it to look like in the file would make this question answerable. A picture is worth a thousand words, a well formed example too.

Comment: It seems to be aligned now! I changed it to tab (which I had before) and it did not work. When I deleted the file, though, and then ran it again everything was aligned properly.